# Deformations of invertible sheaves admitting global sections

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, deformation-theory

We follow Sernesi's treatment of algebraic deformations, working over the complex numbers.

Given a pair $(X,L)$ consisting of a compact complex manifold $X$ and an invertible sheaf $L$ on $X$, we define an infinitesimal (formal) deformation of $(X,L)$ to be a pair $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{L})$ consisting of a complex manifold $\mathcal{X}$ and an invertible sheaf $\mathcal{L}$ on $\mathcal{X}$ such that there is a flat surjective morphism
$$\mathcal{X}\to Spec(A)$$
where $A$ is (the completion of) a local artinian $\mathbb{C}$-algebra, with central fiber $X\to Spec(\mathbb{C})$ and such that $\mathcal{L}|_X=L$.

Suppose we are given such a deformation, and suppose that $L$ has global sections. Is there a neighborhood of $Spec(\mathbb{C})$ in $Spec(A)$ such that $\mathcal{L}|X_{a}$ admits global sections for all fibers $X_{a}$ over the neighborhood?

Can we say something stronger, like the restriction of $\mathcal{L}$ to the fibers is defines a sheaf isomorphic to $L$ in some neighborhood? What if we replace $\mathbb{C}$ with an arbitrary field of characteristic 0?

*Edit* As pointed out in the comments, $Spec(A)$ will have only one point, so a correct question is to ask when does $\mathcal{L}$ admit a global section if $L$ admits global sections?

Comment: Don't local artinian algebras have a single point only? So "for all points in a neighbourhood" is trivially true if it is true for one point. I guess you want a section of $\mathcal L$ over $\mathcal X$?

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. I was thinking of complex deformations when formulating the question.

Comment: Proposition 3.3.14 seems to give a criterion for when you can extend a section of $L$ to $\mathcal{L}$.

I'd kind of expect this to not always happen: if X is a curve of genus g>1 and L is the trivial bundle O_X, then a general deformation of L on the trivial deformation of X would be a line bundle of degree 0 (and this should admit no global sections).

Comment: @Eoin Proposition 3.3.14 gives a criterion for extending a section to first order deformation, so for $A=k[\varepsilon]/(\varepsilon)^2$, not a general infinitesimal or formal deformation. Maybe it is possible to extend the argument. I just hoped a condition might be known already